# Pixi.js v5 - apply alpha to displacement map

Tags: pixi.js

I'm scaling a displacement map on click but would like that map to fade away once it reaches almost full scale. The idea is that the filter should be non-existent after a couple of seconds.

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  view: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
  width: 512,
  height: 512
});

const logo   = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("https://unsplash.it/600");
const displacement = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541701494587-cb58502866ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
const filter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(displacement);

logo.anchor.set(0.5);
logo.position.set(256);
logo.interactive = true;

displacement.anchor.set(0.5);
displacement.position.set(256);
displacement.scale.set(0.05)
displacement.alpha = 1

app.stage.filterArea = app.screen;
app.stage.filters = [filter];
app.stage.addChild(logo, displacement);

app.ticker.add(function() {
  displacement.scale.x += 0.05
  displacement.scale.y += 0.05
  if (displacement.scale.x > 10) app.ticker.stop()
});

logo.on('mousedown', function() {
  displacement.scale.set(0.05)
  app.ticker.start()
});
```

Here's what I have so far:
https://codepen.io/mariojankovic/pen/pojjNae?editors=0111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only just started looking at Pixi but I think you want to use the scale property of the displacement filter.  This value says how far to shift. Reducing this value to 0 will lessen its effect to none.

https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter.html
https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter.html#scale

> The way it works is it uses the values of the displacement map to look
>   up the correct pixels to output. This means it's not technically
>   moving the original. Instead, it's starting at the output and asking
>   "which pixel from the original goes here". For example, if a
>   displacement map pixel has red = 1 and the filter scale is 20, this
>   filter will output the pixel approximately 20 pixels to the right of
>   the original.

https://codepen.io/PAEz/pen/BaoREwv

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  view: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
  width: 512,
  height: 512
});

const logo = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("https://unsplash.it/600");
const displacement = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541701494587-cb58502866ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
);
const filter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(displacement);

logo.anchor.set(0.5);
logo.position.set(256);
logo.interactive = true;

displacement.anchor.set(0.5);
displacement.position.set(256);
displacement.scale.set(0.0);
displacement.alpha = 1;

app.stage.filterArea = app.screen;
app.stage.filters = [filter];
app.stage.addChild(logo, displacement);

const displacementScaleFrom = 0.05;
const displacementScaleTo = 10 ;
const displacementStep = 0.05;

const filterScaleFrom = 20;// the default value for the filter is 20
const filterStep = filterScaleFrom / ((displacementScaleTo-displacementScaleFrom) / displacementStep);

app.ticker.add(function () {
  displacement.scale.x += displacementStep;
  displacement.scale.y += displacementStep;
  filter.scale.x -= filterStep;
  filter.scale.y -= filterStep;
  if (displacement.scale.x >= displacementScaleTo) {
    app.ticker.stop();
    filter.scale.x = 0;
    filter.scale.y = 0;
  }
});

logo.on("mousedown", function () {
  displacement.scale.set(displacementScaleFrom);
  filter.scale.x = filterScaleFrom;
  filter.scale.y = filterScaleFrom;
  app.ticker.start();
});
```

Comment: Although it doesn't address the alpha channel issue it does solve my main problem. From what I see, you've basically downscaled the filter but upscaled the discplacement map which is really clever. Thanks!

Comment: @twenty I should have explained what it does, so sorry.  I couldnt find an alpha and assumed you wanted the pixels to end at their starting position mainly and saw that could do it.  And what you made looked cool which is why I wanted to see it aswell.  Now I wouldnt mind seeing the alpha version.  Could just overlay a second tHiNg (still learning pixi) or I could change the source for displace filter.  Looked and its easy enough, but, um, I kinda have to learn some things on import first, the shader stuff looks simple enough.  Ill update the post in the next couple of days.